# Stop Spark executor logs from getting gzipped

Tags: apache-spark, emr, amazon-emr

I have a Spark job with some very long running tasks. When the tasks start I can go to the executors tab and see all my executors and their tasks. I can click on the `stderr` link to see the logs for those tasks which helps a lot for monitoring. However, after a few hours the stderr link stops working. If you click on it you get `java.lang.Exception: Cannot find this log on the local disk.`. I dug into a bit and the issue seems to be that **something** has decided to gzip the logs. That is, I can still manually find the log by ssh-ing to the worker node and looking in the correct directory (e.g. `/mnt/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1486407288470_0005/container_1486407288470_0005_01_000002/stderr.gz`). It's annoying that this happens since I now can't monitor my job from the UI. Also, the files are pretty tiny so the compression doesn't seem helpful (40k uncompressed). It seems like there's a lot of things that could be causing this to happen: yarn, a logroller cron job, the log4j config in my Yarn/Spark distro, AWS (since EMR zips logs and saves 'em to S3), etc. so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction so I don't have to search a ton of docs.

I'm using AWS EMR at `emr-5.3.0` without any custom bootstrap steps.

Comment: So, is this intermittent ?

Comment: Yes. It happens only to long running jobs and doesn't always happen to all executors.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar issue. I haven't searched how to stop gzip from happening, but you can access the logs using the hadoop interface.

On the left menu, under Tools > Local logs

Then browse to find the log you are interested in.

For my case, the gzip from the gui at /node/containerlogs/container_1498033803655_0037_01_000001/hadoop/stderr.gz/?start=-4096
And using local logs menu, it was in
/logs/containers/application_1498033803655_0037/container_1498033803655_0037_01_000001/stderr.gz

Hope it helps